# Oracle update statement with inner join with set value

Tags: database, oracle

I'm new to oracle database. I'm trying to run an update query but it returns an error :

```
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Here is my query :

```
UPDATE GTP_CUSTOMER_REFERENCE
SET GCR.REFERENCE='0000001'
FROM GTP_CUSTOMER_REFERENCE GCR
join gtp_company gc on gc.abbv_name = gcr.customer_abbv_name
WHERE gc.name in ('AAA', 'BBB')
```

Appreciate every help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct syntax in Oracle. You can use `exists` as follows:

```
UPDATE GTP_CUSTOMER_REFERENCE GCR
SET GCR.REFERENCE='0000001'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gtp_company gc WHERE gc.abbv_name = gcr.customer_abbv_name
AND gc.name in ('AAA', 'BBB'))
```

Or you can use `merge` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO GTP_CUSTOMER_REFERENCE GCR
USING (SELECT DISTINCT gc.abbv_name AS abbv_name
         FROM gtp_company gc 
        WHERE gc.name in ('AAA', 'BBB')) GC
ON (gc.abbv_name = gcr.customer_abbv_name)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET GCR.REFERENCE='0000001'
```